# Find all needed assemblies for a Type's implementation to compile successfully

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, code-generation, codedom

What is the Reflection way to get all assemblies that are needed for a Type's implementation (a .cs source file) to compile successfully?

Suppose you have the source file with the implementation of this Type only (no other implementations).

For example

Assembly MyAssembly.dll declares this interface

```
public interface IInterface { byte[] Array { get; } }
```

Assembly MyAssembly2.dll declares this abstract class

```
public abstract class MyTypeBase: IInterface
{
   public byte[] Array { get; set; }
   protected virtual void Execute(ConfigurationManager cmgr) { }
}
```

In source file "MyType.cs" there is the implementation of MyType

```
public class MyType<T>: MyTypeBase
{
   protected override void Execute(ConfigurationManager cmgr)
   {
        Array = new Byte[512];
   }

   public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then, for the type `MyType<DateTime>` the assemblies needed to reference would be:

- `mscorlib` (Because of `DateTime, Byte, Byte[], List<DateTime>`)
- `MyAssembly2.dll` (Because of `MyTypeBase`)
- `MyAssembly.dll` (Because of `IInterface` indirectly referenced by `MyTypeBase`)
- `System.Configuration` (Because of `ConfigurationManager`)

This is going to be used in a dynamic compilation scenario, and I don't know how deep and where I have to look for Type referenced by a certain type (implemented interfaces of that type, inherited classes, return types, method arguments, events etc)

For instance, is it necessary for the example above, to reference `MyAssembly.dll` since it is referenced indirectly and not directly by `MyType<DateTime>`?

**Update:**

As I said this is going to be used in a dynamic compilation scenario, but i forgot to mention that there would be no source file to compile, but a CodeDOM CompilationUnit instead. So each referenced type in the initial Type is well known (by reflection).

All I want is, for a given Type instance at runtime, to find all the assemblies that **would** be needed as references if I had to compile this Type's source code.

Comment: This seems strange to me; how framework is supposed to know your MyTypeBase is implemented inside MyAssembly2.dll?

Comment: @RubensFarias At runtime, using reflection you can always take a reference to a Type's assebmly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: as you said, "at runtime"; your scenario is 'pre' runtime, or at assembly compilation, so that's my doubt.

Comment: Yes, I was not clear on that. I would take a type at runtime (with reflection) and I will try to find all assemblies that WOULD be needed if I had to compile this type's source

Comment: There's a difference (sometimes) between the assemblies you need to reference to compile a type, and the assemblies you need to reference if the code you're compiling itself uses that type. Do you need the former or the latter?

Comment: I need the assemblies to compile the type. Not the one's to use it.

Comment: Correction, I need the assemblies to compile the type's interface (if i was to extract an interface from that type). Not the actual implementation. I don't care if inside a method's body, there are object instances of types that won't ever get exposed as return values or arguments etc.

Comment: Did you actually get the answer somewhere else? If yes, can you please post it here?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't in-line with how the C# language works.

As I understand it, there's no way to see the token `Byte` and know unambiguously that the caller meant `System.Byte` from `mscorlib`. They could mean their own `Byte` implementation from their own namespace, or even a `System.Byte` implementation from their own namespace.

This is why, as an application developer, you are required to indicate the libraries you wish to reference and then remove any ambiguous references.

---

If you want to see the types which are required by a type's interface, you can use reflection to iterate over all public (and protected) members of the type and see what types they accept as arguments and return.

You will also have to look at the base types and interfaces of all referenced types they could also be declared in a separate assembly.

Every `Type` instance exposes an [`Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which you can use to locate the assembly the type was found in by the AppDomain which loaded the type. That might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: I was not so clear on that. The scenario does not involve compiling of a source file. At runtime I will get a Type as input and the output should be all the assemblies that WOULD be required to reference if I had to compile this Type's source code